# Django creating custom captcha

Tags: python, django, web, captcha

I have to create custom captcha in Django and don't really know how to. What I have are only images with captchas. What's the best practice making my own captcha? Create a new app inside the project? And what next? I don't really need code examples, just the idea, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question will most likely get closed because it's asking for a recommendation, which is largely opinion-based instead of a specific programming question about code you've written.

However, I'll offer a shameless plug for a captcha I wrote to give you some ideas, or better, just use it and save yourself a lot of time: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-simple-math-captcha

Comment: Thanks! I think I will use some of your code at least :D